# ArcGIS how to geolocate/georeference raster data arrays?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geolocation

How does one geolocate (or georeference) a raster of swath grided data with separate lat/lon arrays and multiple data bands using ArcMap 10.3?

A sample data file (*.h5) can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gwn23weeu3msa6/SMAP_L1C_S0_HIRES_01430_D_20150509T083014_T12373_001.h5?dl=0)

A simplified data structure is:

Subdataset 1: lats

Subdataset 2: lons

Subdataset 3 to end : data bands

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.